# file upload fails with slow network bandwith in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, upload, connection

I've got a code working fine that uploads a file to a DJANGO server.

It works fine on a fine connection.

Now if, using fiddler to simulate a slow connection....page freezes (Chrome pop up offering to kill the page).

I've tested in different ways and the only factor that causes the error is a slow upload speed. e.g. If I choose a wi-fi network it fails but over the ethernet it works.

File is 100MB!.

python: 2.7.6
DJANGO: 1.5.5

Any ideas?